# Django: AJAX/jQuery in Admin

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-admin

I have a Contract class where contract_mod allows to extend a contract from a previous one. contract_mod should only show contracts related with the person that we selected previously. As I've never work with AJAX/jQuery I don't know where to start.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    person        = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    project       = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank = True, null = True) #related project
    contract_mod  = models.OneToOneField('self', blank = True, null = True) #allows to extend a contract
    type_contract = models.CharField(max_length = 9, blank = True, verbose_name = _(u"Type of contract(Full time/grant/Partial time...)"))
    starting_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    ending_date   = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - I don´t think the contract_mod will work like this; I guuess you want a list of contracts of the person? For this you don´t need a onetoone field. Let alone to `'self'`.

In stead, you can simply use a [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to retrieve all contacts of the person in your logic section, something rougly like: `Contract.object.filter(person=person)` (I can't be very specific because you give very little information about your class logic and how you want to do things.)

2 - This is all backend stuff. Even if you wanted to make a view with it, this would still be considered backend stuff. If you want to retrieve these things with an ajax call, using jquery, as it appears to be from your question, please ask in a different question how to do this, because it is a frontend thing, django-agnostic.

But in a nutshell, you could create a view with the results of your query, and pass it into a json or xml to the frontend, in stead of for example a template.

Comment: The class works properly with  'self' [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) it's just that I need to add the jQuery functionality and I need it in the Admin. I've seen there're some third party extensions that provide this functionality but I'd prefer keep the code _clean_